# NameError wrong constant name primary — yet `primary` doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apartment-gem, ruby-on-rails-6

I am getting an error that randomly pops up whenever I make changes. If I refresh the page after getting the error, it goes away. The error:

```
NameError wrong constant name primary
```

I have searched my entire application and I do not have any methods or constants using the word `primary`. Why is my Rails application trying to call something that doesn't exist?

Comment: I've had this happen on an upgrade to Rails 6 too, haven't found anything about it.

Comment: Interesting @Eyeslandic ... did you also get the problem where Application controllers and model changes required a server restart? I tried doing what people did here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25186 ... but it doesn't work for me. I wonder if these are related.

Comment: Yes, that describes it exactly, I just downgraded, don't need anything from Rails 6 at the moment. But hopefully someone has an explanation.

Comment: This is the first time I'm developing on the bleeding edge. I was kind of expecting some pain going into this. I'll let this question linger a bit longer and then open an issue on rails/rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so it looks like this will be fixed in the next release. The fix was referenced here:
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36757

So, wait a week or two, update Rails and this will be resolved.

Edit: As a workaround, I reverted from 6.0.0.rc2 to 6.0.0.rc1